# parameterized query with where like clause

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0, parameterized-query

I am trying to perform parameterized query with where clause like 
I got no errors but I am not getting data but when I perform same query 
on sql server studio I got correct result

what the wrong with it ?

one last question in some case I would may not to pass one of these like parameter then how to avoid binding that parameter to query ?

```
public void GetPatientInfoFilter()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRJDconnstr"].ToString();
    string cmdStr = @"SELECT ID,
                                             DocNUM,
                                             NAM+' '+LFNAME as FirstLastName,
                                             FNAME,
                                             SEX,
                                             BIRTHDAY,
                                             PHONE,
                                             MOBILE,
                                             ADDRESS
                                  FROM SICK
                               WHERE DocNUM LIKE @DocNUM
                                    AND NAM+' '+LFNAME LIKE @FLNAME
                                    AND FNAME LIKE @FNAME";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        dtPatientInfo.Rows.Clear();
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocNUM", SqlDbType.VarChar,10)).Value = "%" + TB_DocNum.Text + "%";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FLNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar,200)).Value = "%" + TB_FirstLastName.Text + "%";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar,100)).Value = "%" + TB_FatherName.Text + "%";


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtPatientInfo);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtPatientInfo;
    }
}
```

here is how I perform query in SSMS

```
SELECT ID,
                                                     DocNUM,
                                                     NAM+' '+LFNAME as FirstLastName,
                                                     FNAME,
                                                     SEX,
                                                     BIRTHDAY,
                                                     PHONE,
                                                     MOBILE,
                                                     ADDRESS
                                          FROM SICK
                                       WHERE DocNUM LIKE '%1%'
                                            AND NAM+' '+LFNAME LIKE '%sa%'
                                            AND FNAME LIKE '%b%'
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a wildcard match, e.g., DocNUM LIKE %xxx% ?  Might be a good idea to show your query that works...

Comment: How did you execute the query in SSMS? You can't specify multiple values in a T-SQL variable. Did you*hard-code* the values? Another *BIG* problem is that you defined all parameters to be `VARCHAR(1)`. Your parameter values will get truncated to a sincle character

Comment: Another big *performance* issue is that `NAM+' '+LFNAME LIKE @FLNAME` prevents the server from using any indexes. It will have to scan the entire table to calculate `NAM+' '+LFNAME` before it can test. Are you expecting `@FLNAME` to contain spaces? If not, why not use `NAM LIKE @FLNAME` ?

Comment: I suspect you really want is [Full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) and FTS indexes. You could use eg [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#comparison-of-like-to-full-text-search) to search for partial matches in both fields with `WHERE CONTAINS((Nam,FNAME), @FLNAME)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please see my post update I perform same query and I get correct result

Comment: @sam it's not the same query at all. You are using *hard-coded* values there. Apart from that, you didn't specify a length for the parameters so they default to 1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have not defined any thing to VARCHAR(1) it will get it I am using this way previously a lot ... it wont truncate anything

Comment: @sam you typed `new SqlParameter("@FLNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)`. That has a default length of 1. In any case, if you want arbitrary searches *and* good performance you need to use FTS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos CONTAINS is not available with sql server 2008r2

Comment: @SAM you didn't say which version you are targeting. FTS was already available in SQL Server 2008 R2 anyway. And you *have* to specify a parameter length

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it gives me error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONTAINS'.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please I need this to work I will check books later there is dateline  for me if you do not mind to show me an example or how to make think works here

Comment: If you surround your input text values with "%", that might fix it.. e.g, `.Value = "%" + TB_DocNum.Text + "%";`

Comment: *SET THE PARAMETER SIZE*!

Comment: @lan woow your answer works '.Value = "%" + TB_DocNum.Text ' but one last question please what if in some cases the user  does not enter data in e.g `TB_DocNum.Text ` the query will fail if you have answer please post bot of them and I wll mark it as answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos post updated with parameter size sorry I made you upset thank you sorry again

Comment: Fail?  You mean the empty value will match all records?  What would you prefer?

Comment: @LAN I mean when one of these param not entered by user the query will return nothing e.g if user not entered data in the `TB_DocNum` the `.Value = "%" + TB_DocNum.Text ` will bind null and query will be like  `WHERE DocNUM LIKE '%%` which match nothing as i tested and ill get noting even if the rest is correct

Comment: `WHERE DocNum LIKE '%%'` will match all rows

Comment: @lan when I test it it not getting result when there is null in a  column as value

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting the `%` wildcards into the textboxes? I bet you want this:

```
string cmdStr = 
    @"SELECT ID,
         DocNUM,
         NAM+' '+LFNAME as FirstLastName,
         FNAME,
         SEX,
         BIRTHDAY,
         PHONE,
         MOBILE,
         ADDRESS
     FROM SICK
     WHERE DocNUM LIKE '%' + @DocNUM + '%'
         AND NAM+' '+LFNAME LIKE '%' + @FLNAME + '%'
         AND FNAME LIKE '%' + @FNAME + '%'";
```

You might also consider removing the leading wild cards, and only doing "starts with" matches, since what we have here prevents any possibility of any indexes helping this query.

Comment: please if you mean with "starts with" matches linq it wont work with me because I need to update the datatable with search result and in that case datatable will have all the data not only the search result.... finally if someone can help me with if user not entered a data in the textbox the query will fail ? am I right ?

Comment: @sam No. "Starts with" just means `FNAME LIKE @FNAME + '%'` rather than `FNAME LIKE '%' + @FNAME + '%'`, so that searching for `am` would not find `sam`, but searching for `sa` would still find `sam`. This makes a **huge** difference for database performance, and it tends to be what users expect for name searches anyway. Now, when you have longer free-text fields, users expect more of a "contains" search like you were attempting... but in this situation, there are better index options available, too.

Comment: #Joel uh it okay i got it any suggestion about case I talked about it in comment above ?

Comment: Add code to check for an empty textbox before running the query.